# does anyone still make competitive chromoly frames for road biking?

Tags: road-bike, steel

Chromoly frames can be constructed relatively light if the quality is high enough.

Does anyone know of any brands that concentrate on making modern chromoly frames for entry level competitive cycling?  i.e. litespeed is to titanium 
as x is to chromoly

Thanks!

Comment: For entry level competitive cycling, my guess is that the frame and weight aren't so important anyway.

Comment: http://www.somafab.com/bikes-frames/frames Specifically the 'Smoothie' might be down your alley

Comment: For entry level racing, aluminum has the best price/weight/stiffness combination. You can sure get a steel frame that gets close in the latter two categories, but the price is not going to be entry level.

Comment: The answer is "yes", and the rest is product recommendation. So I'm voting to close.

Comment: @ojs that's both off topic and opinion not an answer, which is not really the point.

Comment: ...which is why it was a comment, not an answer. My answer would be "no, currently made steel frames are either not suitable for racing or too expensive for entry level"

Comment: Haha Moz is coming in here way too hot

Answer (score 1):

The best place to start would be all-city:
http://www.allcitycycles.com/bikes/space_horse

or Lemonde as a second option:
https://lemond.cc/#!/bicycles

Comment: Neither of those bike are entry level competitive cycling.  First is not a race bike and on the second $3000 is not an entry level price.

Answer (score 1):

Bianchi still sells the [Vigorelli 105](http://www.bianchiusa.com/bikes/road/all-road/vigorelli-105/) as well as other steel bikes. With an MSRP of $1800, it's a little pricier than some other Shimano 105 bikes on the market, but it's not too expensive as to be unreasonable.  According to [this article](http://www.bikeradar.com/us/road/gear/category/bikes/road/product/review-bianchi-vigorelli-15-49303/), it weights 20.59 pounds, which isn't super light, but probably won't be a big deal at the amateur level. 105 level components are more than acceptable for entry level racing. They also have the [Volpe](http://www.bianchiusa.com/bikes/road/all-road/volpe/) with Tiagra components for $1300 and the [Lupo](http://www.bianchiusa.com/bikes/road/all-road/lupo/) with Sora level components for $1050.

Answer (score 1):

Surly is more known for touring and off road bikes, but they do have a cromoly road bike or just hte frame http://surlybikes.com/bikes/pacer/bike_info

There are still plenty of custom frame builders around. Zinn Cycles is in Colarado, so maybe close to you? http://zinncycles.com/Zinn/index.php/test-page/classic-custom-series/merano-st

Comment: "While the Pacer is not what most would consider a racing bicycle".

Comment: Yes, fair comment. Masi sells a cromoly frame http://www.masibikes.com/framesets/gran-criterium or a fully built verions which looks great http://www.masibikes.com/bikes/steel/gran-criterium-2015

Comment: $1000 for frameset only is slightly above what I would call entry level.

Comment: I don't think an entry level steel frame exists, this response shows what options there are. Perhaps second hand is the only affordable option.